# Logical operators in the filter option

Tags: javascript, screeps

How to use two arguments in a filter?

```
var source3 = Game.spawns.Spawn1.pos.findClosest(Game.SOURCES_ACTIVE, {
    filter: function(object) {
        return object.id != source1 && source2;
    }
}).id;
```

Because my filter only considers the argument 'source1'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you add the comparison in the second part as well `object.id != source2`

```
var source3 = Game.spawns.Spawn1.pos.findClosest(Game.SOURCES_ACTIVE, {
    filter: function(object) {
        return object.id != source1 && object.id != source2;
    }
}).id;
```